# WSO2 ESB is adding slash in payloadfactory

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

i am using payloadfactory mediator and adding single slash value in arg but ESB is converting it into double slash below is the payloadfactory which in using along with response

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
     <format>
        {
            "channel": { 
                    "text": "this is test Text $1"
            }
        }
     </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" value="\n" />
        </args>
  </payloadFactory>
```

Payload is set to

```
{
    "channel": { 
        text": "this is test Text \\n"
    }
}
```

and i want.

```
{
    "channel": { 
        "text": "this is test Text \n"
    }
}
```

P.S "\n" will be set above in property mediator and i will put it in payload factory through arg, thats why i cannot use it in format directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a limitation in the ESB. Please try the following workaround. (Yeah I know. It seems like an overkill)

```
<enrich>
        <source type="inline" clone="true">{
    "replace" : "\n"
}</source>
        <target type="body"/>
    </enrich>
    <property name="NEW_LINE" expression="json-eval($.replace)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>        {
            "channel": { 
                    "text": "this is test Text $1"
            }
        }
     </format>
        <args>
            <arg literal="true" evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:NEW_LINE"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```